# Ethics and concerns about feeding human placenta to humans?

Tags: medical-ethics, obstetrics

Background:

- Placenta is served out of a typical kitchen, i.e. it is chopped up
  and used in a variety of dishes.
- The kitchen after the event is never cleaned to any degree that say a
  surgical room would have been.
- The kitchen continues to be used to cook meals.

Should there be any concerns about prions or any other blood born pathogens?

Prions can be found in the [Placenta](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20804341) as can blood born pathogens(?). It is common practice for Surgical tools to be sterilized with autoclaves. Rooms where surgeries performed cannot obviously be put into autoclaves.

What can be expected of normal cutlery that has been through the dishwasher a few times and kitchen counters which have been cleaned in a typical fashion? The oven has probably just been used for cooking subsequently.

Would this be resolved after a few years?

I haven't found anything in any literature that touches on this subject.

Oregon made it legal to take home and consume Placenta, but all of the articles I have found discuss having the placenta shipped off to a companies who do the actual job butchering it up and sending back for just the mother to consume as dry tablets. There is one article I have read from the [CDC](https://www.cdc.gov/mmwr/volumes/66/wr/mm6625a4.htm?s_cid=mm6625a4_e#contribAff) where they talk about one case involving the consumption of it.

Nothing I found discusses the ramification of people doing this in their homes.

---

Comment: Why don't the two links you provided answer your question?  Yes, there are prions and yes, eating uncooked human tissue presents a risk of bloodborne pathogens even if it's your own tissue.

Comment: The paper on prions in preeclamptic and normal pregnancies shows that prions are measurable in preeclamptic, but it doesn't say that prions are found in all normal pregnancies.
The CDC is just a single case, and then conditions are not the same. I didn't find that it provided an answer to my question. It is a referenced article in cases examining Oregon's legalizing placenta consumption. 
I haven't found anything that suggests that Oregon considered the science and/or health concerns before enacting laws on the subject ( FWIW I don't live in Oregon )

Comment: Okay, maybe the prion question isn't answered to your satisfaction, but the bloodborne pathogen question would be answered immediately by a simple google search. Consuming uncooked animal tissue of any sort always presents a risk of infection.